# gstreamer rtspsrc port unreachable

Tags: python, gstreamer

BLUF: when I do not run a gstreamer process in a shell, I see ICMP port-unreachable packets, that appear to degrade my connection until the network camera hangs up.
Why might this be?

I have a gstreamer pipeline which has a problem with hangup; after some indeterminate period of time, the camera will terminate the connection and gstreamer will continue to "record" video but not receive any additional data.
Think of it as filling a cup from a faucet, and somebody turns the water off while you still have the cup under it.
The gst-launch pipeline looks like `rstsprc do-rtsp-keep-alive=true ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink`.
Filesink and rtspsrc have their arguments to set source and destination, which I've omitted for clarity.
Also, for production, I am using python gstreamer bindings; I am aware that gst-launch is a debugging tool, not a real solution.

Running the pipeline above in bash with gst-launch-1.0, I do alright; the connection stays alive until I send a sigint.
Running the same command in a python subprocess, I see the characteristic hangup behavior.
Running the same command in a python subprocess *with shell set to True*, I do not see the hangup behavior.

From a tcpdump, I'm seeing that the host sends a lot of ICMP: Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable) messages to the camera in the hangup case, and I'm not seeing those messages when the command is run in a shell process.

It seems like running gstreamer in a shell environment is slightly different, from the perspective of port reachability, than running it in a non-shell environment.
What is happening?